# ViewController and Enyo

Tags: javascript, enyo

There is a new MVC mechanism built in Enyo 2.3pre but there is absolutely now docs on it.

The question is how can I bind specific controller to my view?

I have a new kind based on enyo.Control e.g. and I have a controller based on kind: 'enyo.ViewController',

In my controller I have handlers object with a function that should handle event.

If I put view prop into controller with a name of my view that doesn't work since
my handler in controller is not invoked

Can you post some examples on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the enyo.ViewController, by default, wants to renderInto document.body and we use it to define the enyo.Application kind as the "starting point" for your application.

The Enyo implementation is not necessarily "pure" MVC in the sense that you don't necessarily have to have a proper controller for every view (or enyo.Control) that you are dealing with.  Enyo has always had a sort of hybrid view/controller system baked into the controls themselves.

With that being said, recent changes to the implementation removed bubbling of events to a "controller" that owned your "view" as it resulted in a lot of unnecessary overhead.  In fact, we're removing the "controllers" block from the enyo.Application kind as an app-global reference to various controllers, and instead you will place them in a components block as typical of "traditional" Enyo development.

So, the current thinking is that your view will handle events as before, but you can bind to properties of various "controllers" and models.

Now, you can still create an MVC architecture if you really want to, but the system is flexible enough to support any of the "separation of concerns" methodologies (MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc.)

My current way of going about things is to create a "controller" for doing some things (like make Web service requests) and then build out models from the data I get back, add them to a collection, and then my views probably have a data-aware control (such as enyo.DataRepeater or enyo.DataList) that will automatically generate some rows for each model.

Take a look at this simple example:  http://github.com/clinuz/college-football  but, be advised it may not be up-to-date with the switch from app-wide controllers to components.  And also, we're removing the "controller" property of the DataRepeater/List and it will change to "collection."

Let me know if you need some more hints.  We're aware the lack of documentation is making this difficult while we finalize our implementation.  Please bear with us!

Comment: Thanks a lot, sugardave! I've managed to make it work just by adding my whole controller to a parent View and by setting a 'view' property in this controller.

Comment: I've checked your example and I have a few questions on this: 1. There is 'controllers' property which references to a Scoreboard which is Model, not a controller. 2. There are no ViewControllers or Controller in this example. Should I use them?

Comment: It's really going to boil down to your specific needs.  The ability to bind any component's property to any other component's property sort of negates the need to have a "controllers" array in that main app kind, hence the mentioning that it will change to just be a components block in the Application kind.  Technically, there is ONE ViewController in that app (the main Application itself, as enyo.Application extends from enyo.ViewController)

Answer (score 2):

You could see my example of to checkout enyo MVC structure. 
https://github.com/prajnavantha/enyo-internetradio

Basically we have a model, view and controller.
models: In my case is a simple enyo.Model kind. U can have enyo.collections etc...
Controller: i've used enyo.ModelController.
Views: have the kinds:

The application is not totally MVC. Since my logic is still in views. However you can understand, how to set model and use the componenets.